# Determining Account Type from table and Registering Session

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically what i am trying to do here is to read from the table in my database using the customers login details, then retrieve the record that matches this information. In this table there is a column called "AccountType", this differentiates the average user from a manager, if this column is 1, they are a average user. If this column is 2, they are a manager.

Now im having issues implementing this in my code, below is the snippet of my process script for the login:

```
<?php

***session_start()

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'", $db) or die ("Query failed with error: ".mysql_error());

$count=@mysql_num_rows($query);

if(***$count == 1)
    {
    ***$user_row = mysql_fetch_array($result)

        $userid = $user_row["userid"];    
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;

        $customername = $user_row["customername"];    
        $_SESSION['customername'] = $customername;

        $AccountType = $user_row["accounttype"];

        if ($AccountType == 2)
        { 
            $_SESSION['manager'] = $AccountType;
        }
```

Depending on this, when my check login script which every page includes, it will display specific links on the navigation depending what there account type is, if they are user they will have access to normal links, but if they are a manager they have access to admin functions, below is the code snippet for this also:

```
***session_start();
if (***isset($_SESSION['userid'])) 
{
    $employeeid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $firstname = $_SESSION['customername'];

    if (***isset($_SESSION['manager'])) 
    {
        $User_Options .='Manager links go here';
    }

    else
    {
    $Links .='Normal Links go here';
    }   

}
```

Thats just a basic truncated version, but that gives the basis of what im trying to accomplish. I am guessing down to using the while loop its overwriting the session, which i understand, however there will only be one record for the information i am searching. It works to some extent, however even if the AccountType is 1, it displays the options for 2.

Can anyone assist me further in solving this issue? Thankyou!

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: session_register() is deprecated as well. use `$_SESSION['manager'] = ...` instead.

Comment: Can you put `print_r($user_row)` in your while loop to see what the output of your query is and post the results for us to see, just to make sure you are getting the right results.

Comment: Fair point, i do apologise about the deprecated functions, i was just coding as i knew, i shall make the corrections. However, i am still confused as too why the above isnt working, and also reading the PDO tutorial you have linked, how even if i made the changes as you have listed, that would fix the issue im having, if you could explain further i would great appreciate it. Mrmryb, i shall do that now, and update this post, one moment

Comment: Using PDO won't solve your problem, it's an unrelated recommendation because mysql_* has been deprecated.

Comment: Why are you using a `while` loop to handle a result set that will return at most one row? Also the comment from Truth about using prepared statements is important, because the query as it stands now is vulnerable to SQL injection attack.

Comment: Okay sorry it wont let me edit the comment, heres the results Mrmryb: Array ( [0] => 1 [userid] => 1 [1] => testname [customername] => testname [2] => testusername[username] => testusername [3] => testpassword [password] => testpassword  [4] => 1 [accounttype] => 1

Barmar: I understand, this is why i was slightly confused, whilst i do appreciate any advise given, and i will be looking into using PDO's im still unsure as to why my code is not distinguishing between 1 and 2.

Comment: I was using a While loop because i honestly didnt know better, if you have any other reccomendations to executing the query and placing the result into the array? and i understand its vulnerable, this is only for a test project at the moment in time. I shall look into this further once completed :).

Comment: I have edited your post to remove the depreciated functions to get you on the right track, the only thing I left was your mysql query since you should really learn more about that yourself to get the full effect. I don't know if you'll be able to see it though until it is reviewed. I do not intend for the edit to be the solution to your problem, although worth a shot, but itll make things easier for us too for figuring out what's wrong. It seems like your query is returning the right result so that's not the problem. I'd suggest using Barmar's suggestion now and telling us what happens.

Comment: Also for debugging sometimes a simple echo can go a long way, try changing your code to: `if ($AccountType == 2)
        { echo $AccountType;
            $_SESSION['manager'] = $AccountType;
        }` to see if this is the problem or the other section. Some notes about my edit: everything I've changed has ***, session_start() is needed on the start of every page that uses sessions when you no longer use the depreciated session_register,count==1 will make sure you are not getting too many rows.

Comment: Just to update mrmryb and Barmar, i applied the changes you have both listed and its working now, thankyou so much for your help.

To everyone else who has posted, i appreciate your comments in regards to the functions that i have used that are deprecated, and i will look into everything youve listed and hopefully be able to improve upon this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this on the login form:

```
$_SESSION['manager'] = false;
if ($AccountType == 2) {
  $_SESSION['manager'] = true;
}
```

then later:

```
if ($_SESSION['manager']) {
  // display manager-only options
} else {
  // display user-only options
}
// Display options for everyone here
```